Spacing problem (underfull box)
I have the following problem: I have a theorem environment where I nested an enumerate environment. This environment is at the end of a page, and in the subsequent page, LaTeX starts producing horrible white spaces. I don't know how to solve the issue.

How can I solve the issue?
Preamble:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} %add ,twoside to 12pt to have the header turn on each page.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} %removes crap indentation from footnotes
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} %allows you to draw curly brackets
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumerate} % for lowercase roman numbers with enumerate
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,
          includehead,       
          left={2.2 cm},
          right={2.2 cm},
          top={2.2 cm},
          headsep={17 pt},
          headheight={1.0 cm},
          bottom={2 cm},
          ]{geometry}
\linespread{1.2}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10 pt}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{selectionassumption}{Selection Assumption}
\newtheorem{myrestriction}{Restriction}
\newtheorem{implication}{Implication}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{\parskip}
\usepackage{xurl} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,     
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    }


Point of the document where this happens
\begin{proposition}\label{Propequilibrium}
   Under assumptions \ref{Profitable}-\ref{NoDeterrence}, the game admits a unique symmetric Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium in which: 
   \begin{enumerate}[(i)] 
   \item If costs are low and pooling efficiency is strong, retailer $i$ plays $p_i^{int}(p_j)$ while the ABSP sets $m^{int}(p_a+p_b)$ and grants positive surplus to the subscribers; both the equilibrium retail price $p_i^{*,int}$ and rental fee $m^{*,int}$ are increasing in the unit costs and decreasing in the pooling efficiency. As rental becomes more relevant for consumers, the retail price declines and the rental fee increases. 
   \item If costs and pooling efficiency are intermediate, retailer $i$ plays $p_i^{kor}(p_j)$ and the ABSP behaves as a monopolist; the equilibrium retail price decreases with the unit cost and increases with the pooling efficiency and the decay factor.
   \item If costs are high and pooling efficiency is weak, both the retailer and the ABSP behave as local monopolists; the retail price is independent from both the decay factor and the pooling efficiency.
\end{enumerate} 
\end{proposition} 
\noindent Proposition \ref{Propequilibrium} reveals that there are three possible scenarios in equilibrium: first, for low unit cost and strong pooling efficiency, the rental provider equates marginal profits to zero and the subscribers earn positive surplus [...]


you should provide an example.  Presumably there is some unbreakable box at the start of the following page but it is very hard to debug page breaking if you show no example. You have removed all flexibility from section headings which makes page breaking difficult
